# problem on performing increment in an expression

Tags: c

When i compile this code,it showing an error as lvalue required as increment operand

```
int main(void)
{
 int x,y,z;
 x=8++;
 y=++x++;
 z=(x+y)--;
 printf("x=%d,y=%d,z=%d",x,y,z;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `(x+y)--` to do? `--` means to subtract 1 from the variable and assign that back to the variable, but there's no variable to assign back to.

Comment: What is `8++` supposed to mean? You can't change the value of `8`.

Comment: It seems like you don't understand the difference between `++` and `+ 1`.

Comment: `++` cannot work on constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `something++` or `++something` it's roughly equivalent to

```
something = something + 1
```

(the difference between `something++` and `++something` is in what you get when you assign the result to something else).

Because of this, the operand of `++` has to be something you can assign to.

`8++` is equivalent to `8 = 8 + 1`, but you can't assign to a number.

`++x++` would be equivalent to something like `(x = x + 1) = (x = x + 1) + 1`, I can't even fathom what this could be intended to mean.

`(x+y)--` is equivalent to `(x + y) = (x + y) - 1`. You can't assign to an addition expression (which variable would you be setting)?

You should only use `++` or `--` when you actually want to update a variable. It's not a general replacement for `+ 1` or `- 1`. So your program should be:

```
x = 8 + 1;
y = 1 + x + 1;
z = (x + y) - 1;
```

This will print

```
x = 9, y = 11, z = 19
```

Answer (score 0):

constant cannot be changed. `8` is a constant value. `(x+y)` is also not the value which can be incremented and stored somewhere.

`x++` uses the value of `x` then increments the `x`. So the lvalue is changed itself not only the result of the operation.

correct is

```
z=(x+y)-1;
x=8+1;
```